# UITableView datasource issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to make a basic custom cell and after I followed the tutorials I'm getting this issue.

`reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections;
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array1 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";

CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

/*if (! customCell) {
    NSArray *parts = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cell" owner:nil options:nil];
    customCell = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
}
*/

customCell.lblTime.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
customCell.lblEvent.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return customCell;
}
```

Also I have set the Identity on the tableView but still it is not working and I'm using Storyboard. Moreover I have did linked the `datasource` and `delegate`. Please where would be my issue?

Comment: Have you tried breaking in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and seeing if customCell is nil after the call to dequeue?

Comment: Please check your cell static or dynamic and check if you have given correct number for section and row in your .m delegate class

Comment: @Jonathan I checked now customCell is nil. What should I do?

Comment: @JanderXlav It is dynamic. numberofsection return 1;

Comment: @CAN What number are you returning for numberOfRows?

Comment: check the cell identifier from storyboard and it should be under the identifier name not restoration ID

Comment: It depends on your datasource numberOfRows show how many row will be displayed in each section.

Comment: @Jonathan I am returning [array1 count];

Comment: @JanderXlav I've write it on the identifier name but I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @JanderXlav it worked after I have fill the identifier not crashing anymore but empty field!

Comment: I am writing comment as an answer please follow that. And if you like it give it an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first execution the cell is nil . So write code to initialize the cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView : (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
       NSArray *parts = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
       cell = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.lblTime.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblEvent.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It is running but the table view is empty. Can you help me more?

Comment: Make sure that the variables lblTime,lblEvent are properly mapped to the labels present in the CustomCell.

Comment: also check the count of array1

Comment: I have debugged array1 one and the data comes right! I am getting this issue testCelll[7876:306314] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1)look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"

Comment: in the file inspector, first tab. Unticking "Use Autolayout" or use the code [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

Comment: It works after I untick "Use Autolayout" but is there another was instead of unticking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63402/discussion-between-can-and-lineesh-k-mohan).

Comment: use [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom cell inherited from UITableViewCell? Can you show us your custom cell code? Also you may try:

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and not `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` , If you look at the documentation,

for,

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath
```

> For performance reasons, a table view's data source should generally
>   reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view maintains a
>   queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has
>   marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when
>   asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues
>   an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the
>   class or nib file you previously registered.

for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` ,

> For performance reasons, a table view's data source should generally
>   reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view maintains a
>   queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has
>   marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when
>   asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues
>   an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the
>   class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available
>   for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method
>   returns nil.

Notice  "this method returns nil" .

FYI, do not forget to register your cell Nib before you use the methods using, `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

Since you are using Storyboard, make sure the "Resuse Identifier" in the storyboard and the the one you are using to create the cell are the same.

Comment: This is not what's causing the problem. If the method (the old one) the OP is using to dequeue a cell returns nil, then the new longer one will also (because of missing or incorrect identifier). The only difference, given the OP's code, is which line will cause the crash. Also, the OP said he is using a storyboard, so you shouldn't register a nib in that situation.

Comment: @rdelmar , You are right. I missed the Storyboard part. I just gave some more information that may help OP out.

Answer (score 0):

First answer solved your error: Check the cell identifier from storyboard and it should be under the identifier name not restoration ID

Second answer: You need to put a breakpoint where you fill your cell.lblTime.text and if it is empty check where you fill your array and try to understand why it is empty. Fill free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the table view in storyboard and cell also in it , then i think you might not have set the cell identifier in storyboard.

set the reuse identifier of your storyboard cell to "MainCell"